# Restream a mp3 stream over https with ssl

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, icecast

I need to restream several existing mp3 streams over https.

I have a current stream with the url :
http://cdn.stream.com/radio.mp3
and I would like to have it as :
https://cdn.newstream.com/radio.mp3

I have seen several solutions such as :

rebuild my own cast with icecast

nginx proxy

stunnel

cloudfront (could be expensive)

or a paid service : https://www.autopo.st/secure-streams/

But couldn't find an simple tutorial with a cheap solution using AWS.

Is there any way to secure an existing stream in a cheap way using AWS ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running Debian or Ubuntu, just install Icecast from the official Xiph.org repositories:

https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Installing_latest_version_(official_Xiph_repositories)

It has TLS support built in.

The certificate needs to be provided as a *combined* file, with both public and private key in the same file. In case of Letsencrypt - some ACME clients can natively produce that sort of output.

As you don't specify if you control the origin server or need to relay an external server I won't venture into further explanations, please clarify your question if you need specific aspects covered.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't have control over the origin server. Please check below to see what I ended up doing.

Comment: WTF, indeed. How did I miss that… Yeah, if it's a static file, forget about icecast!

Comment: I think I am not streaming a static file, it's a radio mp3 streaming file.

Comment: Why did you call it file.mp3 then? Also then using a traditional web server is highly discouraged, resource inefficient and hard to set up in a stable way.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding :/ I have updated the question.

Answer (score -2):

With the help of a freelancer, here is what I ended up doing.

I register a domain mydomain.com and pointed it to a ubuntu machine hosted Hertzner to get a good value for money on network traffic.

So mydomain.com is pointing to the ip of the server 130.130.130.130

run this on the machine :

```
cd /usr/local/bin
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/lnk9mriccwydhow/caddy
chown root:root /usr/local/bin/caddy
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/caddy
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/caddy
groupadd -g 33 www-data
useradd   -g www-data --no-user-group   --home-dir /var/www --no-create-home   --shell /usr/sbin/nologin   --system --uid 33 www-data
mkdir /etc/caddy
chown -R root:www-data /etc/caddy
mkdir /etc/ssl/caddy
chown -R root:www-data /etc/ssl/caddy
chmod 0770 /etc/ssl/caddy
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mholt/caddy/master/dist/init/linux-systemd/caddy.service
cp caddy.service /etc/systemd/system/
chown root:root /etc/systemd/system/caddy.service
chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/caddy.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start caddy.service
```

create the file /etc/caddy/Caddyfile with this content

```
securedStream.mydomain.com {
proxy / http://originStream.com 
}
```

Then run these one to run caddy to add autostart, start and check status

```
systemctl enable caddy
systemctl start caddy
systemctl status caddy
```

Access to https://securedStream.mydomain.com/

Comment: Just to be clear on what you've done here... you've set up a normal HTTP proxy, just as you would have with Nginx or similar.  Instead of getting your binaries from somewhere trusted though, it appears you let your freelancer put them on Dropbox.  Unless you know how those binaries were built, and you trust who put them there... that's sketchy.  Also, how are you going to get updates now in the future?

Comment: Another word of warning. Traditional web servers are  **not** designed for continuous streams. You'll waste a lot of incoming bandwidth (each client connection causes one connection to the origin), but also memory consumption. Also more than a hand full of client connections might make the server seize. (depending on default limits)

Comment: @TBR. Thanks for the warning. What do you think would be a cleaner solution ?

Comment: My answer applies. Use Icecast to relay the stream. Set it up for TLS. It works.